# Can't re-render html in vee-validate component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vee-validate

> Vue.js v2.6.11 / vee-validate v3.2.2

I have a button that will push new element to **form.demand** (data in vue app) on click event.
And if **form.demand** update, html in **v-for** should be updated.
After I wrap it in vee-validate component , it not works.
**form.demand** will update, but **v-for** won't.
I try to put same html in test-component, when **form.demand** update, **v-for** update too.
I can't figure out why...

following is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<test-component>
  <div v-for="demand in form.demand">{{demand}}</div>
</test-component>

<validation-provider rule="" v-slot="v">
  <div @click="addDemand">new</div>

  <div v-for="(demand,index) in form.demand">
      <div>{{demand.name}}</div>
      <div>{{demand.count}}</div>
      <input type="text" :name="'demand['+index+'][name]'" v-model="form.demand[index].name" hidden="hidden" />
      <input type="text" :name="'demand['+index+'][count]'" v-model="form.demand[index].count" hidden="hidden" />
  </div>
</validation-provider>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
Vue.component('validation-provider', VeeValidate.ValidationProvider);
Vue.component('validation-observer', VeeValidate.ValidationObserver);

Vue.component('test-component',{
    template: `
        <div>
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#content",
    data: {
        form: {
            demand: [],
        },
    },
    methods: {
        addDemand(){
            this.form.demand.push({
                name : "demand name",
                count: 1
            })
        }
})
```

------------Try to use computed & Add :key----------------
It's still not work. I get same result after this change.

**HTML**

```
<validation-provider rule="" v-slot="v">
      <div @click="addDemand">new</div>

      <div v-for="(demand,index) in computed_demand" :key="index">
           <!--.........omitted.........-->
</validation-provider>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: "#content",
        // .......omitted
        computed:{
            computed_demand() {
                return this.form.demand;
            }
        },
    })
```

I think I found the problem : import Vue from two different source. In HTML, I import Vue from cdn. And import vee-validate like following:

vee-validate.esm.js

```
import Vue from './vue.esm.browser.min.js';
/*omitted*/
```

validator.js

```
 import * as VeeValidate from './vee-validate.esm.js';
    export { veeValidate };
```

main.js

```
// I didn't import Vue from vue in this file
import { veeValidate as VeeValidate } from './validator.js';

Vue.component('validation-provider', VeeValidate.ValidationProvider);
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- at end of body -->
    <script src="/static/javascripts/main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

After I fix this( import vee-validate from cdn, or import Vue by ES6 module). 
It works, although it still have infinite loop issue with vee-validate.

Sorry for I didn't notice that import vue from two different source.

Comment: This is most likely a reactivity issue. 
Use a getter for fetching the `form` object if you are using vuex.

Else make a computed property instead of using `method addDemand`

Comment: Thanks. I am not using vuex. I modified my code, use computed value, but it still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a key in you v-for. see code below

```
<div v-for="(demand,index) in form.demand" :key="index">
      <div>{{demand.name}}</div>
      <div>{{demand.count}}</div>
      <input type="text" :name="'demand['+index+'][name]'" v-model="form.demand[index].name" hidden="hidden" />
      <input type="text" :name="'demand['+index+'][count]'" v-model="form.demand[index].count" hidden="hidden" />
  </div>
```

Or, make a computed property that will hold your form.demands array, like this one

```
computed: {
   form_demands: function() {
     return this.form.demand
  }
}
```

then call this computed property in your v-for

```
<div v-for="(demand,index) in form_demands" :key="index">
      <div>{{demand.name}}</div>
      <div>{{demand.count}}</div>
      <input type="text" :name="'demand['+index+'][name]'" v-model="form.demand[index].name" hidden="hidden" />
      <input type="text" :name="'demand['+index+'][count]'" v-model="form.demand[index].count" hidden="hidden" />
</div>
```

Or, use the vue forceUpdate method

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.forceUpdate();
```

Then in your component, just call the method after you add demand

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```

> It is recommended to provide a key with v-for whenever possible,
>   unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally
>   relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've modified my code following your suggestion. But I get same result. I do the same thing in test-component, it's work. Maybe this is vee-validate issue?

Comment: Sorry for I didn't notice that import vue from two different source. I've update my question. Maybe that is the reason.